# How to select values and key in a Dictionary of lists?

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have this data :

```
public class MetaLink
{
    public long LinkNumbering { get; set; }
    public long TargetPageId { get; set; }
    public string TargetUrl { get; set; }
    public LinkType LinkOfType { get; set; }
}
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<MetaLink>> Links = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<MetaLink>>();
```

How can I obtain all index of `MetaLink` object in the list dictionnary values and the correspondig dictionnary key with `TargetUrl` property  == "Some value"

Perhaps is possible with Linq, but I don't find it.
I do this :

```
var someLinks = Links.Values.Where(kvp => kvp.Any(ml => ml.TargetUrl == "Some value"));
```

But I can't get the correspondig dictionnary int key

Comment: Your run-on sentence is really hard to parse. It would be much easier to help if you if you'd give a concrete example with sample input and expected output - ideally with what you've tried so far, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close - you want

```
var someLinks = Links.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Any(ml => ml.TargetUrl == "Some value")) 
                           // all key.value pairs where the Value contains the target URL
                     .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);   //keys for those values
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on this. Haven't compiled.

```
var key = Links.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Any(ml => ml.TargetUrl == "Some value")).Select(x => x.Key).SingleOrDefault();
```